# Is it possible to determine the type of media inserted into an optical drive on Redhat Linux (7 or 8)

Tags: rhel, disk, dvd

I am working on a user interface for moving data to and from an optical drive. Customer wants to support any type of drive, cdrom, dvd, blueray and all the various configurations. Since the write capabilities varies greatly between these media, it would be useful to be able to determine what type of media is inserted into the drive. So far the closest answers I have found are related to determining if Media is inserted or not, but not the type of media.

Comment: udisksctl info ?

Answer (score 0):

dvd+rw-mediainfo will return information about the media inserted into the drive. Have tested on both BD and DVD drives. returns lots of good information about the drive.